# The docs have an example client call to originate a smart rollup using the variable name OPERATOR_ADDR for the "from" account. Is that meaningful?

Tags: smart-rollup

See here (also in the Mumbai docs): [docs/alpha/smart_rollups](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/smart_rollups.html#id2)

Is the originator of the rollup an "operator" in some sense? The documentation describes an "operator" role for the SORU node. What the significance is of the operator for origination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "operator role" when originating a rollup. It's rather just the account that injects the operations, signs it (and pay fee and storage).

Once the rollup is originated on L1, we can have one or more rollup nodes rollups, which one or more accounts playing the role(s) of operator(s).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.